# Is there a way to calculate the volume difference between two objects?

Tags: volumetrics, measurement

I'm relatively new to Blender so apologies in advance in case this is too basic of a question.

Trying to come up with a way to compare two files and identify a volumetric difference between them.

For example, if I get a 3D scan of an apple and then scan it again after a bite has been taken, can I overlay them in Blender and calculate the volume of the difference between those two scans?

Thanks to all in advance

[image: Apple Scan]

Answer (score 6):

If you go to edit>properties>Addons and enable the 3d print toolbox add-on then click on the 3d-print tab on the right side of your viewport you can click volume to get a numerical value for the volume of the object. From there you can either get both volumes and do the math yourself or you can bool the 2 objects and use the 3d-print tools to get the volume of the result.